# Index matrix with randomly sampled columns

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to fill the columns of an index matrix with samples from 1:whatever using a for loop.  The purpose of this is for a bootstrap coding problem.  The issue I'm getting is that the for loop wont run correctly once it reaches a number that is not a multiple of the row length.  For some reason it thinks I want an equal representation of number in each column.  How do I get this to stop?

```
index.mat=matrix(NA,nr=12,nc=10,byrow=FALSE)
for(i in 1:5)
{
  index.mat[,i] <- sample(1:i, i, replace=TRUE)
  print(index.mat)
}
```

will print

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    1    2    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [2,]    1    1    2    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [3,]    1    1    2    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [4,]    1    1    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [5,]    1    1    2    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [6,]    1    1    2    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [7,]    1    1    2    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [8,]    1    1    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [9,]    1    1    2    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[10,]    1    1    2    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[11,]    1    1    2    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[12,]    1    1    2    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

as the final matrix before giving the error

```
Error in index.mat[, i] <- sample(1:i, i, replace = TRUE) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `sample(i, size = 12, replace = TRUE)`.

Your LHS is `index.mat[,i]` which has length 12.

Your RHS is `sample(1:i, i, replace = TRUE)`, which has length `i`.

By nature, `R` will recycle the RHS when the lengths don't match up -- this means, when `i=2`, your RHS is length 2 and it will simply be repeated 6 times to match the LHS length 12.

In this particular case, if the RHS length isn't a divisor of the LHS length, you get an error -- which happens first when, you guessed it, `i=5` (since 1, 2, 3, and 4 all divide 12 evenly).

Comment: Like I said, I can't do that.  This is part of a bigger problem that I simplified to put on this site.  It has to be done in a for loop.

Comment: @pretzelman I don't think you understand what I said. Read again (and perhaps my edit will add some clarity).

Comment: Oh, I understand.  Thanks!  What if I also wants to keep the sample between 1:12 for each of the columns, but say I wanted to fill 1000+ columns?  would I use 

sample(12, i, replace=TRUE)

Comment: @pretzelman The first argument to `sample` is the set from which to draw, the second argument is the number of items to draw. Learn to read the help pages and use named parameters to avoid such confusion in the future.

Comment: @pretzelman in that case, you should ditch the loop. `matrix(sample(12, 12*ncols, TRUE), nrow = 12)`

Comment: @MichaelChirico I see.  Thanks for your help!